# Unable to jump to row 0 on MySQL result index 13

Tags: php, mysql

What is the reason of the error on title? I tested mysql query at Mysql Front and no problem. My script is below. Thank you.

```
$fbFoodPerma = $fbSiteID."-".$fbFoodPerma;  
    $sql = mysql_query("  
        SELECT fbFoodPerma   
        FROM fbFoods   
        WHERE fbFoodPerma   
        LIKE '$fbFoodPerma'") or die(mysql_error());  
    $isStored = mysql_result($sql,0,"fbFoodPerma");  
    while ($isStored == "$fbFoodPerma") {  
    $fbFoodPerma = $fbFoodPerma."-";  
    $sql = mysql_query("  
        SELECT fbFoodPerma   
        FROM fbFoods   
        WHERE fbFoodPerma   
        LIKE '$fbFoodPerma'") or die(mysql_error());  
        $isStored = mysql_result($sql,0,"fbFoodPerma");  
        }
```

Comment: looks like this query returned no rows.

Comment: I tested query on Mysql Front. It returns a row.

Comment: Also script was working for a month. It was returning this error rarely but stacked now.

Comment: @Ahmet 
you better get rid of this obsolete mysql_result function. use mysql_fetch_row/assoc instead. you have also very unusual logic in your code. I can't get it at all

Comment: There's really lots of weird stuff in that code. Are you absolutely positive this query even returns enough rows? Try to see if anything is returned with the `mysql_num_rows()` function. And also you might want to go for `mysql_fetch_row()` or `mysql_fetch_assoc` instead of `mysql_result`.

Comment: I think I should also explain why I am using this? This is just to generate a permalink. So I am checking whether permalink generated before or not. Is it wrong using mysql_result for that? And what is the difference between mysql_fetch_assoc and mysql_result?

Comment: `mysql_result()` lets you specify which row to retrieve, so you can in theory jump forward over multiple rows and cherry pick just the rows you want. `mysql_fetch_*()` will only retrieve the NEXT row available in the result set. Details here http://php.net/mysql_result and http://php.net/mysql_fetch_assoc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hmm, try this to see if it is picking up any data at all:

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM fbFoods";
$query = mysql_query($sql) or die ("Could not match data because ".mysql_error());
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($query);

if ($num_rows > 0) {
    echo "rows found";
    } else {
    echo "none found";
}
```

Also make sure that `$fbFoodPerma` actually contains something - try echoing it at the end of your query.

```
echo $fbFoodPerma;
```