# PHP Error: Unable to jump to row 0 on MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

For some reason, PHP is throwing the error on my web server but not locally:

```
Warning: mysql_result() [function.mysql-result]: Unable to jump to row 0 on MySQL result index 16 in /home/a8576801/public_html/indev/core/functions/users.php on line 79
```

Now, the function in question at line 79 goes as such:

```
function user_id_from_username($username) {
    $username = sanitize($username);
    return mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT `user_id` FROM `users` WHERE `user_name` = '$username'"), 0, 'user_id') or die(mysql_error());
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that the query is working?

Comment: Try replacing the variable $username with a value you know is correct and see what it returns. You probably have a problem in the variable value rather than the query itself.

Comment: Yes everything else is working. I can see, create and edit fields from `users`. Also, I forgot to mention, it's working locally just not on the web server.

Comment: Is this is Line 79 `return mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT `user_id` FROM `users` WHERE `user_name` = '$username'"), 0, 'user_id') or die(mysql_error());`

Comment: Did you created authorized connection to web server db?

Comment: @Dipak Yes and yes. you can see for yourself actually: http://indev.kolbengames.com/

Comment: do a echo $_POST['username']; on that page and tell me the output

Comment: mysql_result() will throw E_WARNING if mysql_query returns 0 rows. This is unlike any of the mysql_fetch_* functions so be **careful** of this if you have E_WARNING turned on in error_reporting(). You might want to **check mysql_num_rows() before calling mysql_result()**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow ok sorry everyone. Dumb mistake on my part. I called the function in the wrong file.

FIXED !

Comment: and correct your query it will break soon , if query returns no results. Writing code in hast , looks smart succinct but I do not see how you catch exceptions

Answer (score 0):

It might be that $username is NULL. Echo the username and confirm there is a value associated with it.

might want to check out [Unable to jump to row 0 on MySQL result index 13](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2708896/unable-to-jump-to-row-0-on-mysql-result-index-13) as well

Comment: This isn't really an answer, you should use the comment feature to post things like this. I personally don't mind, but a lot of people on here will down-vote answers which are really just comments and I hate to see people lose reputation for things like that. :)