# Unable to jump to row 0

Tags: php, mysql

I have strange problem, after renamed (and updated on query) MySQL tables when I perform search I receive this warning:

> Warning: mysql_result() [function.mysql-result]: Unable to jump to row 0 on MySQL result index 8 in D:\dev\search.php on line 94

Here my code:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM admin WHERE ((`status_desc` LIKE '%".$search."%') OR ('%".$search."%')) LIMIT 100";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
$num = mysql_numrows($result);
```

Line 94 is `$status_id`:

```
<?php
$i=0;
while ($i < $num)
{
    $status_id = mysql_result($result,$i,"status_id");
    $status_des = mysql_result($result,$i,"status_desc");
?>
<tr>
    <td><a href="config_status_edit.php?status_id=<?php echo $status_id; ?>"><?php echo $status_id; ?></a></td>
    <td><?php echo $status_desc; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php
    $i++;
}
?>
```

What's wrong?
(I have planned update to PDO but at moment I need to use mysql_query)

Comment: It's `mysql_num_rows` not `mysql_numrows`. Now try `$num = mysql_num_rows($result);`

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you want to read your query like that instead of the regular ways?

Comment: Sorry, typing error, but not solve problem :-(

Comment: @user2307958 So it's not your actual code then. What is `line 94`?

Comment: @Prix. No, but script was originally developed in this way...

Comment: @Fred: Line 94 $status_id = mysql_result($result,$i,"status_id");

Comment: did you check that the query returns some results?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Warning: mysql\_result() \[function.mysql-result\]: Unable to jump to row 0 on MySQL result index 5 in profile.php on line 11](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12649594/warning-mysql-result-function-mysql-result-unable-to-jump-to-row-0-on-mysq)

Comment: Do the columns status_id and status_desc actually exist?

Comment: @prof and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2708896/unable-to-jump-to-row-0-on-mysql-result-index-13

Comment: @all, i got error, it's an include with another query which create conflict to get results. It's strange, but work to solve this.

Thanks for ALL :-)

Answer (score 0):

Use the mysql_fetch_* functions instead of `mysql_result`

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM admin WHERE ((`status_desc` LIKE '%".$search."%') OR ('%".$search."%')) LIMIT 100";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

while ( ($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) ) {
   $status_id = $row["status_id"];
   $status_des = $row["status_desc"];
?>
   <tr>
      <td>
         <a href="config_status_edit.php?status_id=<?php echo $status_id; ?>">
            <?php echo $status_id; ?>
         </a>
      </td>
      <td><?php echo $status_desc; ?></td>
   </tr>
<?php
}
```

It will loop through till it has no more rows to fetch, no need to setup/check counters etc.

Comment: Well that doesn't answer the question as to why his method is not working but in fact this would be a better way to read it.

Answer (score 0):

Verify `$num`

```
if ($num > 0) {
    echo "rows found";
    } else {
    echo "none found";
}

 WHERE (`status_desc` LIKE '%".$search."%' OR `status_desc`LIKE '%".$othersearch."%')
 WHERE (`status_desc` LIKE '%".$search."%' OR `other_column`LIKE '%".$search."%')
```

Run your query in the sql client i suspect this is the problem.